# Why is $\sin(\tanh x) + \sinh(\tanh x)$ almost exactly $2\tanh x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

I was trying to come up with some approximations for the solution to the differential equation $y'' + \operatorname{sgn}(y') + y = 0$ and noticed while I was messing around that $\sin(\tanh x) + \sinh(\tanh x)$ is almost exactly $2\tanh x$. Looking at the series expansions for $\sinh$ and $\sin$ it's not immediately obvious why this would be the case. It makes sense that high-order terms should converge to a constant value for large $x$, and that near $x=0$ they should be approximately zero. This seems to imply that for some intermediate values of $x$ around something like $x=0.5$ there should be disagreement, but this seems like a remarkably good fit for every value of $x$. Why might this be?

Comment: Because $\sin(x)\approx\sinh(x)\approx x$ for large enough values of $x$ that asymptotic behavior takes over before there's really any difference.

Comment: $\sin x\approx x$ for *large* values of $x$?

Comment: @JoshuaWang You mean small enough.

Comment: large *enough*, the function goes to $1$ so quickly that the small deviation from $x$  does not really matter. It helps that the second components of the Maclaurin series of $\sin$ and $\sinh$ cancel out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can ignore the $\tanh$ component momentarily and consider instead the function
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x + \sinh x}{x}.$$  This has series expansion
$$f(x) \sim 2 + \frac{x^4}{60} + \frac{x^8}{181440} + O(x^{12}).$$  Therefore, on the open interval $x \in (-1,1)$, $f(x)$ has exceptionally small deviation from $2$, thus on the real line, $$g(x) = \frac{\sin \tanh x + \sinh \tanh x}{2 \tanh x}$$ will be very close to $1$.

In other words, it is not simply that $\sin x \approx x$ and $\sinh x \approx x$, but that these approximations are in a sense opposing, thus terms cancel out in the series expansion:

$$\sin x \sim x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + O(x^9) \\
\sinh x \sim x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} + O(x^9) \\
$$
so their sum cancels up to $O(x^4)$, which after dividing by $x$, gives the first nonzero error term being $O(x^4)$.

Comment: The argument being $\tanh x$ also bounds it between $\pm1$, which bounds the error in the OP's approximation.

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, the Taylor expansions are, respectively, $x-2x^3/3+17x^5/60+O(x^7)$ and $x-2x^3/3+4x^5/15+O(x^7)$, so the difference is $x^5/60+O(x^7)$.